# Collapsed comments Like Facebook

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, facebook

I am trying to create a Collapsed comments Like Facebook with 3 lates comments displayed and rest hidden showing their count.I thought of using the CollapsiblePanelExtender  but its not the right tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just an idea:

1st task:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnmakecomment" class="linkhover" Font-Size="11px" runat="server">Comments</asp:LinkButton>

 <asp:Panel ID="pnlMComment" CssClass="" runat="server" Style="overflow: visible; height:0">
  <div class="commentbox">
   <asp:TextBox ID="MakeComments" CssClass="unwatermarkedcomment" runat="server" Width="90%" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Button ID="btnPost" CssClass="submitButton" Text="Comment" runat="server" CommandName="Comment" onclick="Button1_Click" />
<ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxScrapWme" runat="server" TargetControlID="MakeComments"  WatermarkText=" Make Comment" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked" />
    </div>
 </asp:Panel>

<ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpe1" runat="Server" TargetControlID="pnlMComment"  Collapsed="true" CollapsedText="Comment" ExpandedText="" TextLabelID="btnmakecomment"     ExpandControlID="btnmakecomment" CollapseControlID="btnmakecomment" SuppressPostBack="true" />
```

so, above code is for two thing:

```
  1. collapsible Panel will appear with textbox and button after clicking on the btnmakecomment.
  2. on Button1_Click event update your comment table in database.
```

2nd task:

```
<asp:GridView ID="CommentGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false" ShowFooter="true" Width="90%" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="3"  GridLines="None">
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
              <table class="tblcomment1">
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%--show your comments here--%>
                          <%--PageSize of the GridView has the value 3 so only 3 row will be display first--%>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
               </table>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
  <PagerSettings Mode="NextPrevious" NextPageText="Show More" FirstPageText="Show More"
     LastPageText="Show More" Position="Bottom" />
</asp:GridView>
```

now bind the CommentGridView with the comment table.
you can notice there is a PagerSettings in gridview which will appear below the comments, so, on the NextPageText(ShowMore) you can increase the PageSize value to show more comments. like this:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    int i = CommentGridView.PageSize;
    CommentGridView.PageSize = i + 5;
    CommentGridView.DataSource = dtscrab;
    CommentGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Note: for partial postback place CommentGridView inside UpdatePanel.

Comment: Firstly thx a lot for the effort..but ( as there is always a but ) whn i flip to the next page for more comments..not what  i am lokig for ..+ i need to show a count of the label which is at runtime updating..its like [http://www.99points.info/2010/07/facebook-style-wallpost-and-comments-system-using-jquery-ajax-and-php-reloaded/] but its in PhP ..eyo ..

Comment: please check my edit. I have shown you idea it's not complete. you have to work on more in order to achieve you task. And as you made comment: make a count for a label inside the GridView1_PageIndexChanging event.

Answer (score 0):

I once wrote some code to do this, what I found was that in order to do it the way they do, you need to be a bit meticulous.

if its only 1 or 2 comments in a thread, then just load them all into the list.

If there are several comments in the post, you can create a link and then immediately follow that with some newer comments:

```
row 1: <a href="/posts/<post_id>" class="loadMore">show all</a>
row 2: new comment
row 3: newer comment
```

and then facebook uses that href as the ajax url to get the other comments, once it loads in ajax, it replaces that link with the other comments. and then because its set as the href of the a tag, it also degrades gracefully if javascript is turned off.

they were clever in doing it this way

Comment: Ok.but here i am not connecting it with facebook or any other social..I am dealing with my own comments..so i need a look a like.

Comment: in the beginning, you should be less concerned with the look of it, and making sure it works properly... (which is easy since you're consuming your own data), but then just use CSS styling to make it look like theirs.

Comment: Its a little blurred..So you recommending me to use  <a href> to display data ? + i am not worried about the Css

Comment: loading the additional comments should be triggered by some event. I'm proposing you use a click event on an <a> tag via ajax. in your event function, you should stop the link from actually going anywhere. do you understand what i mean?

Comment: you must tnk i am really lame..but i cant get it till i get some code bro ..Sory !